Error al crear modelo con ohana-node-orm
Abajo proporciono el codigo completo, tal cual. La conexion se establece con exito, pero al tratar de crear el modelo para la tabla "@CS_RFFE" se arroja un error debido al caracter "@" del nombre.


const DBConnection = require('../DB/DBConnSAP');
const { connection, ohana } = require('ohana-node-orm');


let conn = new DBConnection();
let settings = conn.connOptions;


const connectionParams = {
    host: settings.host,
    port: settings.port,
    user: settings.uid,
    password: settings.pwd,
    dbname: conn.second_schema
}

connection.connect(connectionParams)
    .then((success) => {
        console.log('Connected');

        const CS_RFFE_Table = new ohana("@CS_RFFE");  
        CS_RFFE_Table.find().then(console.log)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error', error);
    })



Esta es la salida completa en consola
Connected to hana db.
Connected
/Users/soniatoledo/Desktop/agua_vista_sap_node/node_modules/@sap/hana-client/lib/      index.js:53
    ldb.__runCallbacks();
        ^

 Error: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "@": line 1 col 15 (at pos 15)
 at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/soniatoledo/Desktop/agua_vista_sap_node/node_modules/.    @sap/hana-client/lib/index.js:53:13)
at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23) {
code: 257,
sqlState: 'HY000'
}


Hola Sonia, no conozco SAP pero pareciera que no soporta @ en los nombres de las tablas.
